# Equating field momentum with momentum imparted in a charged ring

Tags: electromagnetism, angular-momentum

Consider the classic example of Field momentum to momentum imparted into a charged ring.

Example:

A  positively charged solid ring is on the presence of a uniform magnetic field.

When the magnetic field goes from some $B_{0}$ to 0, the amount of angular momentum imparted on the charged ring is easily calculated

I also know that as the magnetic field goes from some $B_{0}$ to 0, the poynting vector of this field obviously shrinks to 0 everywhere

This is intuitive, as the angular momentum of the field is being converted to angular momentum of the charges.

To solidify my understanding, I wanted to equate the angular momentum of the field before and the angular momentum of the charges after the field has gone to zero, so that I could see that infact they are equal.

However the angular momentum imparted to the ring, is only calculated using the field values that is within the enclosed area that the ring produces.

So when finding the total momentum of the field, if I were to say "cut off" the B field such that only the field that passes through the area remains, I would get the same angular momentum imparted to the ring.

Obviously this would violate the condition that $\nabla \cdot \vec{B} = 0$  so I couldn't actually do this and thus the conclusion that the angular momentum for the cut off scenario is actually false.

A strictly uniform field everywhere though is also not a valid field as there is no curl.

Any suggestions for realistic fields  that I could use to try and equate field and imparted momentum that would actually not violate maxwells equation? I tried thinking about using the field of a straight wire. But then how would I go about finding the angular momentum imparted on the ring without a symmetric B field inside the ring, I guess maybe a qausti static approximation

Comment: Idea: maybe an infinite solenoid is probably the best "realistic" field arrangement I could use to show this

Comment: Be careful. If you have an object with net charge, so that the electric fields go off to infinity, you may find that the change in field angular momentum is not equal to the change in mchanical angular momentum because some angular momentum is being transported to infinity by the Maxwell stress tensor.  This is expecially true for infinite solenoid problems.

Comment: What about an infinite solenoid with a net 0 charge, and then a separate charged ring. The  electric fields will vanish at infinity. What What do you mean the fields will  carry angular momentum to infinity? Surely any transport of angular momentum is accounted for in the field values at infinity and thus a change in the field will shown the exact change in mechanical momentum? Is there any links that you van provide that clarify this further? :)

Comment: And wouldn't this effect violate conservation of momentum?(or poyntings theorem for that matter)

Comment: I mean that if you have a charged cylinder inside the solenoid and another equal and oppositely charged cylinder outside, then switching off the mag field gives torques to *both* cylinders. The total angular momentum transferred to the cylinders in that of the field. So-far so good.  The prblem appears when we make the outside cylinder be so far away that we forget about it. However the $E$ field falls of as $1/r$, but the lever arm for  the torque on the distant cylinder grows as $r$, so the torque on the distant cylinder is independent of its distance. So even at $\infty$ we must keep track.